# Loading a React Native View (RCTRootView) in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, react-native

I'm trying to load an `RCTRootView` in a `UITableViewCell`. The data for the react view is coming from an API.

I am quickly initializing an `RCTRootView` when the detail view loads, and then supplying it with constraints to the UITableViewCell. When the API call is finished and I have the data, I send the data to RCTRootView as `appProperties`.

But at this point, the RCTRootView doesn't size to fit properly with the UITableViewCell. I am calling `tableView.reloadData` after a second or two for the sizing to happen.

What am I doing wrong? How can the performance be improved here?

Answer (score 0):

inside configureCell method of your custom cell, add the following lines of code.

```
func configureCell(){

    let jsCodeLocation = URL(string: "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios")
    let reactView = RCTRootView(
                bundleURL: jsCodeLocation,
                moduleName: "ReactApp",
                initialProperties:  nil,
                launchOptions: nil
            )
            reactView?.frame = self.bounds
            self.contentView.addSubview(reactView!)
    }
```

Dont forget to set the frames..